# Key mappings in Javascript

Tags: javascript, keyboard, key

Is it possible to map key combinations in javascript? For instance, tabs are used to navigate between form element. Now can i map tab to another key (say C-n) and navigate with that key combination?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Would take 2 steps:

1)  Disable built-in tab navigation.  You can do this by adding a tabIndex="-1" property to your input elements

2)  Hook keyboard events with JavaScript to do your own custom navigation.  I would recommend a keybinding library, such as [keymaster](https://github.com/madrobby/keymaster) to help simplify things.

If you don't want to use a library, you'll be interested in the keydown/keyup events, attached at the document level (see the MDC entry for [Keyboard Events](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/KeyboardEvent) for more information).

Comment: keymaster doesn't seem to support that